# How to load 3 static blocks in 3 column layout page magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to create 3 column page layout and want to call three static blocks into that page. Like

> One block to add static data in main content area section,
>
> second block to add data in left side area, and
>
> third one to add data in right side area.

So what should i declare in custom layout file. Like i have declared `layout=3columns` but when i add anything into body section then it will be added to left side area only.
How can i use all these three blocks in 3-column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, After some research i got the final solution. I just need to add 3 reference containers mentioned below and have to add my static blocks inside those.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
     <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="simple.block1" template="VENDOR_MODULE::test1.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="simple.block2" template="VENDOR_MODULE::test2.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <container name="fsd" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="simple.block3" template="VENDOR_MODULE::test3.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```